# Reg upload to artifactory

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

We maintain an artifactory within our intranet which is used by the development team.
When ever any new dependency is added to any project , we upload the new jars into artifactory.

This is currently a tedious process and we are trying to find if there is any simple way out.

The current process is - if a project defines a new dependency , we need to connect to internet and build the project using gradle so that we get to know what are the new dependencies ( we in fact track the logs what are the dependant and transitive dependant jars which are getting downloaded fresh )

Then we create a zip of these new jars alone and upload to artifactory. This is time consuming and error prone as well

Is there any better way to achieve this ? When i build using gradle connecting to internet , is it possible to publish the new dependencies as well to maven local repo or to some new folder so that we can zip that folder alone and upload to artifactory ?

Kindly revert if anybody has a simple solution for the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a maven answer but the same will apply to gradle.

You should be able to define a virtual repository in your artifactory, which is a combination of the local (artifactory hosted) and the maven central repo (internet hosted).

Your maven/gardle users will configure the virtual repository (not the internet) in their settings.xml, then when a dependency is loaded maven will look in repostories in the following order:

1) local user repo at ~/.m2/repo

2) artifactory local repository

3) maven central

Each time a new artifact is loaded from 3 (no one has ever asked for it before) it will be added to 2 and 1, so the next user who calls for that dependency will only ever go as far as 2.

See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories

Comment: Thanks for the response.
We would not be able to connect to MavenCentral from our artifactory machine. Also , for test projects developers maybe trying out new libraries and jars which we don't want to end up in the intranet artifactory. Currently we upload only approved dependencies to intranet artifactory but the process is cumbersome  which we would like to simplify

Comment: I would suggest you use artifactory in the way it's designed to be used, it will be much easier.